# Взаимодействие между языками

Tags: java, c#, unity3d

Есть ли возможность настроить взаимодействие сценариев между `java` и `c#` в `Unity3d`, если да то каким образом?

Comment: например, вставлять код java в проект на С# или наоборот?

Comment: Нет такой возможности. Можно только плагины писать для билда под Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А зачем?
Нет смысла писать одновременно на двух языках в Unity, чем обусловлена такая необходимость?
Вообще можно работать одновременно на 3х языках. (Boo, C#, UnityScript), но это может привести к некоторым последствиям.